# Do classes declared in koin modules referenced by Application so that stay in memory as long as Application lives?

Tags: android, singleton, koin

Koin provide `single` and `factory` to create instance of declared classes.

My colleague argues that Koin creates static instances of those classes and they're not referenced by Application. So they're prone to be garbage-collected or lose control of state when high memory pressure happened in Android system. So we better avoid use Koin if singleton created by koin take up lots of memory.

My question is:

1. Does classes created by koin single{} referenced by Application? Is there source code I should read first before I dive into koin source code to prove that?
2. Does classes created by koin single{} prone to be collected when memory pressure happen in Android? Say if that singleton instance is called SdkManager whose job is to load up 3-5 third-party libraries.
3. Is there any initialization method other than `single` and `factory`?

Answer (score 0):

> My colleague argues that Koin creates static instances of those classes

It is unclear what your colleague means by "static instances".

> they're not referenced by Application

Few singletons in Android are referenced by an `Application` subclass, at least by how I would use the term "referenced".

> So they're prone to be garbage-collected

No. That would make Koin, or any other dependency inversion framework, useless.

> or lose control of state when high memory pressure happened in Android system

If the "system" (device?) runs low on memory, Android terminates processes. That will get rid of all objects in the affected process, whether they are managed by Koin or not.

> Does classes created by koin single{} prone to be collected when memory pressure happen in Android?

No.

> Is there any initialization method other than single and factory?

`viewModel` and `fragment` exist for Android apps. See [the `koin-android` documentation](https://doc.insert-koin.io/#/koin-android/start).

Comment: @ComminsWave  Do classes declared in koin modules referenced by Application so that stay in memory as long as Application lives?

Comment: @Sanjayrajsinh: AFAIK, they are `static` in scope and will live as long as the process lives.

Comment: that means all object which is declare in single{} is hold memory until app is killed ?

Comment: @Sanjayrajsinh: Yes, by default. AFAIK, [`unloadKoinModules()`](https://insert-koin.io/docs/reference/koin-core/start-koin#unloading-modules) will let the objects held by the unloaded modules get garbage-collected.